# Fire-base Cloud Function deploy completed without any error, but Cloud Function doesn't exist in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem that when I deploy JavaScript Cloud Function, it says deploy completed, but when I go to Firebase and check it is just not there. Strange thing is that for TypeScript Cloud Function it works properly.

I did everything the whole preparation like installing firebase-tools etc. by original Firebase video tutorial. I tried to deploy only uncommented hello world function but same results.

I also tried many times to reinit Firebase or even reinstall node and Firebase tools but still the same. Emulating locally doesn't work either you can see in the screenshot.

I will attach screenshot of index.js with project structure on left, firebase.json, deploy and emulate messages in cmd.

index.js:

[image]

firebase.json:

[image]

deploy in cmd:

[image]

emulate in cmd:

[image]

EDIT:
when i deployed with specified function this came up:

deploy with specified function:

[image]

When i deployed with empty firebase.json this:

deploy with empty firebase.json:

[image]

deploy with firebase.json as advised under:

[image]

Sorry for posting pictures, but code doesnt format for me right.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's better to copy text of code and output into the question itself rather than showing screenshots.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are looking at the correct project on the Firebase Console? It's easy to be looking at another project and not realise.

Answer (score 1):

You are not really deploying your function.

See, whenever you deploy a new function, the CLI will show the following message.

```
=== Deploying to '<PROJECT-ID>'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (26.61 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 8 function <FUNCTION-NAME>(us-central1)...
✔  functions[<FUNCTION-NAME>(us-central1)]: Successful create operation. 
Function URL (<FUNCTION-NAME>): https://us-central1-<PROJECT-ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<FUNCTION-NAME>

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<PROJECT-ID>/overview
```

In your screenshot, you are not getting the `Successful` message.

Can you please try deploying your functions with an empty json as the *firebase.json* file?

Be sure to run `firebase deploy --only functions:<FUNCTION_NAME>` in the project's root folder. That way, you are telling the CLI to deploy an specific function, in this case it'd be `helloWorld`.

If you don't see the *Successful* message again, post here the results to try to make it work.

**Edit.**

Try changing your firebase.json to

```
{ 
    "functions":{ 
        "source": "functions/",
         "predeploy": [
             "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
             "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
         ]
    }
}
```

and then deploy again.

Comment: I edited post with screenshots after done what you suggested

Comment: I added some extra things to try in the original answer.

Comment: i got another errors but different ones now, posted screenshot in post. I think it is just my computer something is just wrong with it :D